# Github Repository Page gives 404 error

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages

I created my github page [here](http://ngarcian.github.io) and I've created another repository called [videos](https://ngarcian.github.io/videos/) which also works. However, when I created another one called genandrade, the page is not showing up. what should I do?

Comment: what is the link to the other page

Comment: seems to be up: https://ngarcian.github.io/genandrade/